# Mysql Data Selection

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table and I would like to select some of the data into a form, but I my query is not working. can anyone figure out what is wrong with my query?

[image]

Above the table, I only wanted to show all voucher in voucher_3 and user_id = 1 that has been verified as '1'.

and there is an error when I echo out:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\Application\Apps\xampp\htdocs\newtmk\account.php on line 302

here is my coding:

```
   <tbody>

                            <?php
                                $get_member = "SELECT * 
                                FROM transaction_record_tpg
                                WHERE user_id = '1' 
                                AND voucher = '1'
                                AND (voucher_3 = 'RM 3 Voucher' 
                                OR voucher_3 = 'RM 5 Voucher'
                                OR voucher_3 = 'RM 10 Voucher')
                                ";
                                $run_customer = mysqli_query($conn,$get_member);

                                $i = 0;

                                while($row_orders = mysqli_fetch_array($run_customer)){

                                $id = $row_orders['trans_id'];

                                $description = $row_orders['v_script'];

                                $date = $row_orders['collected_datetime'];

                                $outlet = $row_orders['voucher_3'];

                                $voucher = $row_orders['voucher_code'];

                                $i++;
                            ?>
                        <tr><!-- tr Starts -->

                            <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $outlet; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $voucher; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $description; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $date; ?></td>
                        </tr><!-- tr Ends -->
                            <?php } ?>
                        
                    </tbody>
```

Comment: You need parentheses around your `OR` terms i.e. `(voucher_3 = 'RM 3 Voucher' 
OR voucher_3 = 'RM 5 Voucher' 
OR voucher_3 = 'RM 10 Voucher')`

Comment: If you want to get all the voucher_3 rows that are not empty, you can use WHERE user_id=1 AND verified=1 AND voucher_3 IS NOT NULL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below using bracket for OR condition

```
SELECT * FROM transaction_record_tpg 
WHERE user_id = '1' 
AND voucher = '1' 
AND (voucher_3 = 'RM 3 Voucher' 
OR voucher_3 = 'RM 5 Voucher' 
OR voucher_3 = 'RM 10 Voucher')
```

OR You can try using in operator like below

```
SELECT * FROM transaction_record_tpg 
WHERE user_id = '1' 
AND voucher = '1' 
AND voucher_3 in ('RM 3 Voucher','RM 5 Voucher','RM 10 Voucher')
```

Answer (score 1):

Although your requirement is not clear I guess that the following should do the trick for you:

```
$get_member = "SELECT * FROM transaction_record_tpg 
WHERE user_id = '1' 
AND voucher = '1' 
AND (voucher_3 = 'RM 3 Voucher' 
OR voucher_3 = 'RM 5 Voucher' 
OR voucher_3 = 'RM 10 Voucher')";
```

Since you want `voucher_3` to be one of the `'RM 3 Voucher', 'RM 5 Voucher', 'RM 10 Voucher'`, you'd need to enclose the `OR` statements in parentheses.

You can also check [`IN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) funcion which is usually preferred over multiple `OR` statements as it increases readability.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that `user_id` and `verified` are `INT` columns and you need to check for the `verified` column to be set as `1` and *all* the `voucher_3` rows that are not empty, you can try the following:

```
$get_member = "SELECT * FROM transaction_record_tpg 
WHERE user_id = 1 
AND verified = 1 
AND voucher_3 IS NOT NULL
```